Inputs are not being registered in JavaScript
If I invoke greeting() on page load then I receive nothing in the browser (I am looking to amend h1 accordingly). I have tried console.log on various points and my conclusion is that since I am invoking greeting() upon page load, the userInput() is still an empty string when inputValidator() needs it.
I don't want an event listener such as okBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {*some code here*} in the main code body because when I am doing so, the {*some code here*} runs every time I click on okBtn , and I have some other functionalities as well which I would like to associate with this button's click. Also I would like all my messages to appear in the same h1 and I would prefer not to include additional elements for the above. Thanks
A little side note: upon reloading the page, I get the input (cached data) from before refreshing the page appearing in the browser console when I use console log. Just for my knowledge, is there a way to clear the browser cache upon page reload?
I tried window.location.reload(); but

This doesn't seem to work in Google Chrome and works only in Fire Fox

I am using VS Code Live Server and using this command keeps refreshing my page as it is probably meant to do.




var nameInput = document.getElementById("input");
var questions = document.getElementById("name-move");
var okBtn = document.getElementById("ok-btn");

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
  questions.innerHTML = `Please enter your first name!`;
};

let userInput = () => {
  return nameInput.value;
};

let inputValidator = (val) => {
  okBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (val.length > 15 || /[0-9.*+?><,#^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\]+/g.test(val)) {
      questions.innerHTML = `No numbers or special characters and no more than 15 characters allowed`;
    } else {
      return val;
    }
  });
};

function greeting() {
  let us = inputValidator(userInput());
  questions.innerHTML = `Welcome ${us}! Let's play Rock Paper and Scissors!`;
}
<h1 id="name-move"></h1>
<form action='#'>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type here..." id="input" required>
  <button id="ok-btn">OK</button>
</form>




Can you please show where you are calling greeting()? It's defined here, but not invoked.

Apologies! I called greeting() on next line, soon as I declared it.

When inputValidator() was called, val was an empty string because it was retrieved when the page loaded, before the user added any input. You need to get the user input when they click the button, not before.

I assumed so too, could you please suggest how I could do this and achieve the desired outcome?

MoveuserInput() within your event handler and assign its value to val, rather than passing an expired val to inputValidator().

There's a simpler regex pattern that meets your criteria:  if (/[A-Za-z]{1, 15}/.test(val)) return val;

See this post about clearing browser cache.

You for one want to make that button a type="button" or use an event handler anyway and do an event.preventDefault()

@mplungjan could you please share why I should be doing either of them?

Right now when I click the button the form submits. Is that the idea? If so you will never see the greeting anyway even when you move it around


You can removeEventListener from the button whenever you want to.
You can add as many event listeners as you want to the button's click

now you can just add your event listeners and remove them when required.
this code is a sample, you probably would move the removeEventListener part to the validator to prevent unsubscribing unless welcome message was shown first.
You can see only the second event listener will run after you unsubscribe from the first listener.
I added preventDefault to prevent the form from submitting.
you can add other listeners to the same button after the welcome message to simulate steps, at each step you remove previous listener and add a new one.


var nameInput = document.getElementById("input");
var questions = document.getElementById("name-move");
var okBtn = document.getElementById("ok-btn");

window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
  questions.innerHTML = `Please enter your first name!`;
}

const validateInputValue = () => {
   const val = nameInput.value
   if (val.length > 15 || /[0-9.*+?><,#^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\]+/g.test(val)) {
      questions.innerHTML = `No numbers or special characters and no more than 15 characters allowed`;
    } else { 
       return val;
    }
}

const updateHeading = () => {
    console.log('running click event')
    event.preventDefault()
    questions.textContent = validateInputValue()
    okBtn.removeEventListener('click', updateHeading)
}

const stopEvent = () => {
    console.log('Stopping submit')
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
}

okBtn.addEventListener('click', updateHeading)
okBtn.addEventListener('click', stopEvent)
<h1 id="name-move"></h1>
<form action ='#'>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type here..." id="input" required>
  <button id="ok-btn">OK</button>
</form>




Thank you very much All! I have got it working with all your help actually. So it needed preventDefault() which I had missing. I also took on board another advice to move my logics. Current JavaScript is below. It might still become fickle upon introducing further functionalities but so far so good ;)
let inputValidator = (val) => {
  val = nameInput.value;
  if (val.length > 15 || /[0-9.*+?><,#^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\]+/g.test(val)) {
    return `No numbers or special characters and no more than 15 characters allowed`;
  } else {
    console.log(val);
    return val;
  }
};

function greeting() {
  questions.innerHTML = `Hi ${inputValidator()}`
}

let clickStart = () => {
  okBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    greeting();
  });
};
clickStart();


<form> and form controls have many features that you should be aware of:

There are events exclusively for them:

"input" when the user enters data into a form control

"change" when the user unfocuses from a form control

"reset" when the user clicks <input type="reset"> or <button type="reset"> the parent <form> will clear all of it's form controls. (for <form> only).

"submit" when the user:

clicks a <button>

clicks a <button type="submit">

clicks a <input type="submit">

hits the Enter key when the user is focused on certain form controls.


The default behavior of a <form> when a "submit" event is fired is to send it's data to a server and reload the page.



There are many ways to validate client-side. Validation via HTML is the simplest:
Example 1
<input 
  id="playerName" 
  pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" 
  minlength="1" 
  maxlength="15" 
  title="1 to 15 uppercase and/or lowercase letters"
  required
>


[required] + [pattern] a regex value sets criteria that must be met before a <form> can be submitted.

[required] + [minlength] and [maxlength] sets the range limit on the number of characters that the data must be within before it the <form> can be submitted.

When the "submit" event is fired on a <form> and something is invalid, the process is interrupted and a warning pops up. [title] adds it's text to that warning.



<form> has it's own properties and the HTMLFormControlsCollection API which are terse and succinct. Consider the following layout in Example 2. The common way to reference anything  would be with .getElementById(), .getElementsBy[Name|TagName|ClassName](), .querySelector(), or .querySelectorAll() methods which can get tedious and clunky. Refer to Example 3 which uses form properties and the HTMLFormControlsCollection API.
Example 2
<form id="aux" name="groupA">
  <input id="cache" type="hidden">
</form>
<form id="ui" name="groupB">
  <fieldset name="sets">
    <input name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
    <input name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
    <input name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="sets">
    <textarea id="textA"></textarea>
    <input name="textB">
  </fieldset>
</form>

Example 3
// There are several ways to reference 2nd <form> 
const dotID = document.forms.ui;
const dotName = document.forms.groupB;
const bracketID = document.forms["ui"];
const bracketName = document.forms["groupB"];
const bracketIndex = document.forms[1];

// Create an HTMLCollection (an array-like object) of all <form>s
const formsCollection = document.forms;

// Reference all form controls within 2nd <form>
const ui = document.forms.ui;
const io = ui.elements;

// Create a HTMLCollection of all [name="checkboxes"]
const allChx = io.checkboxes;

// Reference the 6th form control of 2nd form
const textarea = io[7];

// Reference a specific form control just like <form>
const byID = io.textA;
const byName = io.textB; 

/** NOTE:
 *  If a [name] is shared by multiple form controls then it can only be
 *  used to reference all of those form controls as a HTMLCollection.
 *  If the [name] is owned by a single form control then it can be used to 
 *  reference that specific form control as previously mentioned.
 */



The following demo utilizes the majority of what was previously mentioned. Details are commented in the demo.


// Reference <form id="roshambo">
const rps = document.forms.roshambo;
/*
  Reference all form controls within <form>
  In this layout it would be all:
    - <fieldset>
    - <output>
    - <input>
    - <button>
*/
const io = rps.elements;

// Start with initial text in output#message
io.message.value = "Please enter your name";

/**
 * This event handler hides fieldset#intro and shows fieldset#game.
 * @param {object} event - Event object
 */
function start(event) {
  /*
    Prevents the default behavior of <form> when the "submit" event 
    is fired.
  */
  event.preventDefault();
  // Change io.message.value
  io.message.value = `Welcome ${io.playerName.value}! Let's play Roshambo!`;
  // Hide fieldset#intro
  io.intro.classList.add("hidden");
  // Show fieldset#game
  io.game.classList.remove("hidden");
}

/*
  Register `<form>` to listen for the "submit" event and call event 
  handler function start() when the "submit" event fires.
*/
rps.addEventListener("submit", start);
:root {
  font: 4vmax/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

fieldset {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 90vw;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

input,
button {
  font: inherit;
  padding: 4px;
}

button,
[type="button"] {
  width: 4rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.box {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1rem
}

#intro input {
  width: 8.5rem
}

#game {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#game input {
  background: rgb(144 144 144);
  text-shadow: 2px 1px #000;
}

#game.hidden,
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<form id="roshambo">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      &#8203;<output id="message"></output>
    </legend>
    <fieldset id="intro" class="box">
      <label for="playerName">Name: </label>
      <input id="playerName" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" minlength="1" maxlength="15" title="1 to 15 uppercase and/or lowercase letters" required>
      <button>OK</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="game" class="box hidden">
      <input id="R" type="button" value="&#129704;">
      <input id="P" type="button" value="&#129531;">
      <input id="S" type="button" value="&#9986;&#65039;">
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>



